# How can I get ArrayList in recycler view for OnClickListener?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am using two recycler views in my application for displaying data. One recycler view is for displaying project information and into that recycler view I used another recycler view to display images of that project, now I want that if I click on any image I can get the image which clicks on and also array list of images of that project. I used a click listener for it but it does not work fine because arraylist changes when more project gets loaded into it. So how can I do this ? Here is recycler view

```
    private ArrayList<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
     FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<projects, ProjectViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<projects, ProjectViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProjectViewHolder projectViewHolder, int i, @NonNull projects projects)
                {
                    Log.d("counting", String.valueOf(i));
                    imagesRef = getRef(i).child("projectImageUrl");
                    final int count =0 ;
                    imagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                        {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                            {
    
                                imagesList.clear();
                                //Loop which I am running 
                                for(DataSnapshot postSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                            {
                                String urls = postSnap.getValue().toString();
                                Log.d("NewImagesName", urls);
                                imagesList.add(urls);
    
                            }
                                //Recycler View
                                projectViewHolder.all_images.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1));
                                ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(getApplicationContext(), R.dimen.item_offset);
                                projectViewHolder.all_images.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
                                layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()  , LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                                projectViewHolder.all_images.setHasFixedSize(true);
                                projectViewHolder.all_images.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    
    
                                ImagesListAdapter imagesListAdapter = new ImagesListAdapter(getApplicationContext()  , imagesList , listener);
                                projectViewHolder.all_images.setAdapter(imagesListAdapter);
listener = new IRecylerViewInterfaceListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position)
                    {
                        //Sending User to another activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainFullScreen.class);
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Images",imagesList);
                        intent.putExtra("position" , position);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                };
listener = new IRecylerViewInterfaceListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position)
                    {
                        //Sending User to another activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainFullScreen.class);
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Images",imagesList);
                        intent.putExtra("position" , position);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                };
 listener = new IRecylerViewInterfaceListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position)
                    {
                        //Sending User to another activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainFullScreen.class);
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Images",imagesList);
                        intent.putExtra("position" , position);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                };
}

 public static  class ProjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        RecyclerView all_images ;
        public ProjectViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        all_images =(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagesRecyclerView) ;
    }
```

Here is Adapter

```
public class ImagesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesListAdapter.ImageViewHolder>
{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> imagesList;

    IRecylerViewInterfaceListener clickListener ;

    public ImagesListAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<String> imagesList , IRecylerViewInterfaceListener clickListener)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.imagesList = imagesList;
        this.clickListener =clickListener;
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {


        View  v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_item , parent ,false);
        return  new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        String newCurrentImage =  imagesList.get(position);
        Log.d("currentImage",newCurrentImage);
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageView;
        final ProgressBar progressBar = holder.progressBar;
        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).load(newCurrentImage).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource)
            {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource)
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
        }).into(imageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
            return imagesList.size();
    }
```

Here is view
[image]

Comment: Hello! I have a few points about your question. You should split your text in several sentences, in the middle of it it gets really confusing.

Comment: About your app, you really should NOT put a recycler view inside of another recycler view, there will be a lot of bugs relating to view recycling and even if it works, the performance will be bad. You should limit the amount of items (in your case, images) in a item to a small number (like 3) and if you need a lot of items, you should consider a different approach, like showing just the first in the recycler view and having a separate screen to show all the images.

Comment: The view which i am showing right now is my need , I just want to put one functionality that is on click listener for images